# Matlab - hist3 not returning expected output

Tags: matlab, histogram

I was trying to use hist3 to visually display a two-dimensional distribution, however the function behaves unexpectedly. I thought that it returns a 2D histogram (a count) of how many times each pair of numbers in the input matrix occurs, and displays that count at a position in the output matrix whose indices correspond to that number pair, scaled to a factor of 10 (by default) or some other square-matrix size. But this is not what my test examples showed:

For instance, if I define the following input matrix

```
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
```

then the command 
v=hist3(m, [5 5])
has the following expected output:

```
1   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0
0   0   1   0   0
0   0   0   1   0
0   0   0   0   1
```

However for this input matrix:

```
4   1
4   2
4   3
4   4
4   5
```

the output is:

```
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0
```

..rather than (as I would have expected):

```
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1
0   0   0   0   0
```

Can anyone help clear the confusion? THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the default indices values range between 2 and 6 so that 4 is the third index. Try to plot it:

```
figure;
hist3(m,[5 5])
```

[image]

**EDIT**

A way to determine the edges using `hist3`

```
EDGES = {(1:5)-0.5, (1:5)-0.5};
figure;hist3(m,'Edges',EDGES);
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand the reason why hist3 returns that unexpected matrix in my second example. Are you saying I need to use the edges workaround in order to get what I want from it? Also, your first plot has a 2D base of dimensions 6x5 rather than 5x5 as the matrix in my example?!...

Comment: Yeah, well. If you really like to have the bars in the fourth column you have to play with the edges. But if you do not specify the edges matlab will do it automatically.
I think that here you are confused because the indices and the values have the same range. Try to multiply by ten the initial matrix. You will see that the output of `v=hist3(vv, [5 5])` is still the same but the plot of `hist3(m,[5 5])` changes accordingly to the new range of values in the initial matrix.

Comment: did I explain myself?

Comment: sorry for the delay. I think I get why hist3 produces such outcomes, but then again maybe it isn't hist3 that I need to achieve my aim but another function. Or perhaps I just need to call it with a different input argument, or somehow alter its output like with the Edges hack that you suggest? Once again, what I would need is to obtain a 2D histogram (a count) of how many times each pair of numbers in the input matrix occurs, and have that count displayed at a position in the output matrix whose indices correspond to that number pair, as in the examples I gave. Thanks again.

Comment: I think controlling the edges separately as you suggest is actually a good enough workaround (possibly the only one), so I'm going to accept your answer. Thanks again!